# Finding the period of a given function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for some help with finding the period of the following function.$$f(x) =(\sin2x)^2 $$

So i know the following about $f(x) = (\sin2x)$

$$f(x) = 2(sinx)$$

where $P = \frac {2\pi}{B} = \frac{2\pi}{2} = \pi$

So the period of $f(x) = (\sin2x)$ is $\pi $ but what about the function I am looking for, $f(x) =(\sin2x)^2 $

Comment: this question was asked verbatim a week or so ago

Comment: is there a link? i couldnt quite find it

Comment: I couldn't either. It was identical, I will answer again for completeness

Comment: also i have explanation, since $sin(2x) = sin(2x+2π) = sin(2(x+π))$ the period of $sin(2x)$ is $π$.

Comment: which seems to be the proper way to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin(2x)$ has period $\frac{2\pi}{2}=\pi$, as I believe you said.

Additionally, we know that $\sin(2x)=-\sin(2(x+\pi/2))$. Thus squaring we have
$$
\sin^2(2x)=(-\sin(2(x+\pi/2)))^2=\sin^2(2(x+\pi/2))
$$
so the period is now $\pi/2$. This is also easy to see visually in graphing a trig function and its square.

Comment: awesome thanks for your help!

Comment: in the additionally we know that sentence, is there supposed to be that negative sign there/

Comment: yes, adding half a period in the argument of a trig functions spits out the negative